# Right shift string in python

Tags: python, string

nfjg g  g               ddedede f e fe fefefe e f e fefe fe e f eefefe fef e  ef e fe

Comment: You just want to add a space at the beginning ? `shifted = ' ' + base`

Comment: "I tried but could not find any solution"... *what* did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add spaces in the front?

```
>>> s = 'burger'
>>> s = ' ' + s
>>> s
' burger'
```

You can add multiple spaces too.

```
>>> s = 'burger'
>>> s = ' ' * 3 + s
>>> s
'   burger'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.rjust` :

```
>>> s = 'burger'
>>> s.rjust(len(s)+1)
' burger'
>>> s.rjust(len(s)+2)
'  burger'
```